# How to implement Session in Android PHP MySQL?

Tags: php, android, mysql, session, android-sharedpreferences

I am new to native mobile apps. Where can i learn Session when I log into my apps? For example, after login, I want to view my Profile, but cannot catch my userID. Which method is suitable for beginner like me? I have tried SharedPreference but got some error. Is there any good tutorial on session in Android? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You maintain a token at client side (android) and validate the token in the server side (php). If the token is valid show the respective page.